# Is there any benefit of already compress table to compress again in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, compression, oracle19c

I have a Oracle 19 C Data warehouse database, where we compress tables on yearly basis. Is it beneficial to compress already compressed table in Oracle?

I use command:

```
alter table t1 MOVE ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED ;
```

Comment: Few questions: 1) Is Table already Compressed with ADVANCED? If yes, then it won't have much impact. If it is not already Compressed with ADVANCED or QUERY HIGH then compressed with these features will have great impact.

Comment: yes , it is ADVANCED compressed.  Also , if i move this compressed table , will it have any impact over compression ?

Comment: If it is already using ADVANCED compressed then further compression (Upto ORACLE 21c) have no much impact. In ORACLE 23c they are adding new feature. Moving of table means? Moving to different tablespace or to export then import to different environment?

Comment: Move means - moves rows down into un-used space and adjusts the HWM .